# How to use Application.Inputbox "static" in a Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I worked with RefEdit but it gives incredibly inconsistent results ([listed here](https://peltiertech.com/using-refedit-controls-in-excel-dialogs/)). I like the Application.Inputbox solution:

```
Set myRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Sample", Type:=8)
```

Since you can input Text or select cells while it is open. How can I use this versatile Inputbox "staticly" in a Userform? I couldn't find it in "Additional Controls"...
I tried a RefEdit a thousand times and it breaks 999times... so I would like to avoid it - thx

Comment: what do yo mean by "*staticly*"?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I would like to add it as a control object (like refedit or textbox)

Comment: You can't add it. It is a stand alone input box like a message box.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ok.. do you know a textbox solution where the user also can select cells, like in inputbox?

Comment: yes therefore the RefEdit was made. Have a look at [RefEdit Control Alternative](http://shutupdean.com/blog/2015/01/08/refedit-control-alternative/) or Google for "RefEdit Alternative" there are several out there. I guess you will find one that suits your needs.

Comment: Or you call the Application.Inputbox when a user clicks on a textbox in your userform and return the result to your textbox. PS Xabier was a little bit faster than I

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly, but why not do something like below, this will bring up the Input for the range and then add the address details to a Textbox:

```
Sub foo()
Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Sample", Type:=8)
    TextBox1.Text = myRange.Address
End Sub
```